# Does apt-get autoremove remove intel graphics drivers?

Tags: drivers, graphics, intel, gtk

I have been trying to install the gtk+ packages on ubuntu 14.04. I had installed 3.20 of gtk+ & later had to install gtk+3.10.  In the process of doing all this I executed many apt-get commands. One of them was

```
sudo apt-get install libcanberra-gtk-module:i386
```

which asked me to run an autoremove command and I did

```
sudo apt-get  autoremove
```

which removed several packages. I did the  libcanberra install after the autoremove. 
Now when I start ubuntu I am getting "your system is running in low graphics mode" error and I have no desktop environment at all. How do I get it back. I have read several articles on fixing this low graphics error but not clear on what to so. lspci -nn | grep VGA shows "VGA compatible controller [0300]: Intel Corporation Haswell-ULT Integrated Graphics Controlller [8086:0a06] (rev 0b0)".

I am not sure how much of the above detail is relevant for the problem at hand but posting it based on some questions that were asked in other posts. I need to get my desktop env working back again.

Comment: @Vinod answered the question on autoremove, I just wanted to add that I was able to restore my desktop environment by doing an unsniall of gtk+3, I did a' "make uninstall" & my desktop env was up and running.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

To focus on your past experience, if `autoremove` is going to remove "more than you intended", it's only doing that because those packages are no longer depended upon. That happens when you accidentally remove something :)

A common example from the good old days would be removing something Compiz-related. apt-get would show you a list of Compiz packages it was going to remove and you'd miss that `ubuntu-desktop` was also in there. `ubuntu-desktop` is just a meta-package that depends on all the packages that make up the desktop so removing it doesn't directly remove anything...

... But when you do an subsequent autoremove, all those things that `ubuntu-desktop` was the sole dependency... They're going bye-bye.

A few lessons:

`sudo apt-get remove <package>` will warn you what it's going to remove directly. It won't notify you about knock-on effects.
`sudo apt-get autoremove` should also warn you what it's going to do.
Use `apt-get -s autoremove` to do a simulated dry run if you're unsure. You can use that on all apt-get commands.
If you reboot and you're staring at TTY1 wondering what the monkeys you've nuked this time, `/var/log/apt/history.log` should have you most recent activity.
If in doubt, check `ubuntu-desktop` is installed.
Is `autoremove` safe? It's heavy machinery so it's only as safe as the driver... But that said, it's hard to do permanent damage.

Comment: If I do an "apt-get install" before every package that is in the list of autoremove in the history.log file, will I get my desktop back or will it do more damage. I tried a install of "ubuntu-desktop" but am told it is already the latest. What is the best (quickest) way to get my desktop back

Comment: Some of the other comments in forums seem to indicate that reinstalling the intel graphics driver might fix the problem, but I dont see any apt-get way to install intel graphics driver for ubuntu 14.04.2